# Geocoder near not working with mongoid ralls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rails-geocoder

I have a model like this one in which i storing coordinated and address. This model is just for testing.

```
class Geomodel
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid
    field :coordinates, type: Array
    field :address
    before_save :update_coordinates
    def update_coordinates
        self.address = Geocoder.search(self.coordinates).first.address
    end 
    reverse_geocoded_by :coordinates
    after_validation :reverse_geocode  # auto-fetch address
end
```

I am able to storing the coordinate and address. But I am not able to use

obj = Geomodel.near(coordinates: [xx,xx]).
It is showing some  Mongo criteria as shown below.

    `#Mongoid::Criteria
    selector: {"coordinates"=>{"$near"=>[xx, xx]}}
    options:  {}
    class:    Geomodel
    embedded: false>`

It also showing this error when i am converting the object into array for testing.
obj.to_a

`Moped::Errors::QueryFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
    @length=114
    @request_id=18
    @response_to=0
    @op_code=2004
    @flags=[]
    @full_collection_name="staging_development.geomodels"
    @skip=0
    @limit=0
    @selector={"coordinates"=>{"$near"=>[73.8719, 18.6139]}}
    @fields=nil>
    failed with error 13038: "can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { coordinates: { $near: [ 73.8719, 18.6139 ] } }"`

Please help me how to solve the problem or give a link to best tutorial you know regarding query with geocoder.
I am using RAILS 4 and MONGOID gem.

PS: I think this whole error is due to following reason.
     1.Creating scope :near. Overwriting existing method Geomodel.near.
     2.May be due to 2dsphere index .

Answer (score 0):

Re: obj = Geomodel.near(coordinates: [xx,xx])

This is a Mongoid::Criteria "query" and NOT document results from a query.
You have to iterate it with a method like #to_a in order to issue the query to the MongoDB server and get back documents as a result.

Yes, don't define your own scope :near that will overwrite the existing Geomodel#near.

As mentioned in the error diagnostic, you need a 2dsphere index for the geospatial $near query, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/